# Circle collision formula

Tags: c#, collision-detection

I have this formula for simple circle collision detection:

```
private bool CircleCollision(Rectangle Circle1, Rectangle Circle2)
{
    int X1 = Circle1.Left;
    int Y1 = Circle1.Top;
    int X2 = Circle2.Left;
    int Y2 = Circle2.Top;

    int R1 = Circle1.Width / 2;
    int R2 = Circle2.Width / 2;
    int Radius = R1 + R2;

    int dX = X2 - X1;
    int dY = Y2 - Y1;

    if (Math.Sqrt((dX * dX) + (dY * dY)) <= Math.Sqrt(Radius * Radius)) 
        return true; 
    else 
        return false;
}
```

But it just expose detection whenever the two circles have same radius. What am I doing wrong?

**Solved**

```
int X1 = Circle1.Left + (Circle1.Width / 2);
int Y1 = Circle1.Top + (Circle1.Height / 2);
int X2 = Circle2.Left + (Circle2.Width / 2);
int Y2 = Circle2.Top + (Circle2.Height / 2);
```

Comment: Heh! Sorry just a mistake in typing.

Comment: You can dispense with the calls to `Math.Sqrt` -- just test whether `(dX * dX) + (dY * dY) <= Radius * Radius`.

Comment: You don't need to take the square roots. What's the point of rooting both sides? Just compare the squares! :)

Comment: Is `Rectangle.Width` supposed to represent the `DIAMETER` or `RADIUS` of the circle? And why are you using a `Rectangle` to represent something that isn't a rectangle? Seems like a poor use of Objects to me!

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do a `sqrt` to make digits small. It's an additional operation but I'm ok with that.

Comment: In C# local variables and parameters use start with a lowercase letter by convention.

Comment: Since my problem is solved by thanking from @CodeInChaos, I couldn't found any `Circle` data type in C#! And DrawEllipsis just accepts Rectangle. @CodeInChaos I got use to not use polish name types!

Comment: " I do a sqrt to make digits small. " This doesn't help, since your intermediate results are already big. If you're afraid of int-overflows, then you should cast to Int64 *before* calculating the square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if two circles overlap you can do:

```
var radius=circle1.Radius+circle2.Radius;
var deltaX=circle1.CenterX-circle2.CenterX;
var deltaY=circle1.CenterY-circle2.CenterY;
return deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY <= radius*radius;
```

Note that I'm calculating the distance of the centers, not of the top left corners. I'm also comparing with the squared radius so I don't need to use the expensive `Math.Sqrt` function, but that doesn't affect correctness.

Your code doesn't work because you use `Left` and `Top` instead of the position of the center. The difference between the top-left corners is the same as the difference between the centers if the radius is the same. This explains why your code only works in that special case.

Not sure why you use a rectangle to represent a circle. You can calculate the center as `centerX = 0.5*(Left+Right)`. You should also add a check that `Width==Height`, else you might get an ellipse as parameter, and then this algorithm won't work.